# One Signal missing support library- Android SDK

Tags: android, android-support-library, onesignal

**update**
I added to proguard rules -keep class firebase, so now I'm able to get GCM token.
But OneSignal detects as my app still missing Android Support Library.
I had an app before, where I was able to build a signed apk and use One Signal with it.
But now when I checked this app, I experienced when I'm able to build a debug apk with Build->Build APK(s) with set minifyEnabled to false, but when I set minifyEnabled to true, I get the same error for that project too.
After I tried to add **-keep class com.android.support.** ** and **-keep interface com.android.support.** ** but One Signal still detects my app does not contain the Support Library (anyway which support lib??).

I implemented One Signal in my app.
If I start app by 'Run app' in Android Studio, everything work fine.
But if I build an Apk by 'Build->Build apk(s)' or I generate a signed apk, after I install it One Signal dashboard says 'Missing Android Support Library'.
I have read all day tutorials on One Signal site, but I was not able to resolve this issue.
How can I fix it?

I get this error

> 05-10 21:12:21.054 17990-18243/com.aff.index.main.debug E/OneSignal: Unknown error getting GCM Token
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging;
>           at com.onesignal.av.a(PushRegistratorGCM.java:41)
>           at com.onesignal.at.a(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:97)
>           at com.onesignal.at.a(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:37)
>           at com.onesignal.at$1.run(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:84)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.sec.android.app.multiwindow.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.aff.index.main.debug-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.aff.index.main.debug-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.aff.index.main.debug-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at com.onesignal.av.a(PushRegistratorGCM.java:41) 
>           at com.onesignal.at.a(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:97) 
>           at com.onesignal.at.a(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:37) 
>           at com.onesignal.at$1.run(PushRegistratorAbstractGoogle.java:84) 
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

Comment: same problem here

Comment: I solved for now by set minifyEnabled=false and multidexEnable=true (because without it I can't build my app because of 65k methods limit).

Comment: @user3057944 show your progurd-rules and gradle file

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of try and error I'v just found the solution, I used these lines in app/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    ...
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:**3.8.4**'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Note: 3.8.4 is the point and it was used insteadof [3.8.3, 3.99.99]**.

and these dependencies in project/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with the OneSignal v3.9.0. Add these lines into you proguard rules:

```
-keep class android.support.v4.view.MenuCompat
-keep class android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver
-keep class android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat
-keep class android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService
-keep class com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging
```

There is closed issue in their repository
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/533

The full working proguard rules for OneSignal v3.9.0:

```
-dontwarn com.onesignal.**

# These 2 methods are called with reflection.
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient {
    void connect();
    void disconnect();
}


-keep class com.onesignal.ActivityLifecycleListenerCompat** {*;}


# Observer backcall methods are called with reflection
-keep class com.onesignal.OSSubscriptionState {
    void changed(com.onesignal.OSPermissionState);
}

-keep class com.onesignal.OSPermissionChangedInternalObserver {
    void changed(com.onesignal.OSPermissionState);
}

-keep class com.onesignal.OSSubscriptionChangedInternalObserver {
    void changed(com.onesignal.OSSubscriptionState);
}

-keep class ** implements com.onesignal.OSPermissionObserver {
    void onOSPermissionChanged(com.onesignal.OSPermissionStateChanges);
}

-keep class ** implements com.onesignal.OSSubscriptionObserver {
    void onOSSubscriptionChanged(com.onesignal.OSSubscriptionStateChanges);
}

-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.AdwHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.ApexHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.AsusHomeLauncher { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.DefaultBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.EverythingMeHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.HuaweiHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.LGHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.NewHtcHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.NovaHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.OPPOHomeBader { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.SamsungHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.SonyHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.VivoHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.XiaomiHomeBadger { <init>(...); }
-keep class com.onesignal.shortcutbadger.impl.ZukHomeBadger { <init>(...); }

-dontwarn com.google.firebase.messaging.**
-dontwarn com.amazon.**

# Proguard ends up removing this class even if it is used in AndroidManifest.xml so force keeping it.
-keep public class com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler {*;}

-keep class com.onesignal.JobIntentService$* {*;}

-keep class com.onesignal.OneSignalUnityProxy {*;}

-keep class android.support.v4.view.MenuCompat
-keep class android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver
-keep class android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat
-keep class android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService
-keep class com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging
```